# Using comparators in google sheets countif within an arrayfunction

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

I have a sheets formula that presently looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(J:J)=1,"eduProjects",IF($A:$A="",,
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&0)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&1)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&2)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&3)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&4)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&5)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&6)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&7)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&8)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&9)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&10)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&11)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&12)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&13)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&14)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&15)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&16)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&17)+
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&18))))
```

I'm trying to simplify this by using a comparator "<19" in place of all the numbers 0 to 18

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(L:L)=1,"eduProjects",IF($A:$A="",,
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&"<19"))))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in an array. Any ideas how I can simplify this formula?

Comment: pretty sure this is do-able and can be simplified quite a bit, but it's tough to understand in teh abstrat . here's a blank i made you can paste in!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12OznLCHYCKYHYUwjzmlbWC8jDAWI7j6pZQ-7sljns_8/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula:

```
COUNTIF(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R&Projects!$S:$S,$A:$A&"Education"&"<19")
```

- [Countif()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) criterion basically becomes a concatenated string of `column A` + `Education` + `<19`.

---

If my understanding is correct that `Projects!$S:$S` should contains a number value since you concatenate it with `Projects!$B:$B` & `Projects!$R:$R` and tried to compare it with `$A:$A&"Education"&0` concatenated string value.

Then you can use [COUNTIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) to simplify your formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(L:L)=1,"eduProjects",IF($A:$A="",,
COUNTIFS(Projects!$B:$B&Projects!$R:$R,$A:$A&"Education",Projects!$S:$S,"<19"))))
```

- Check concatenated `Projects!$B:$B` & `Projects!$R:$R` if it matches concatenated `$A:$A` & `"Education"`.
- Check if `Projects!$S:$S` is `<19`

---

### Output:

**(`B1` contains your original formula, while `E1` contains the simplified formula)**

[image]

**(Projects Sheet)**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect, I just assume your values based on the formula provided. If possible please provide a sample sheet with your expected output.

Comment: Thanks @Ron M - this worked great. I went ahead and populated the blank sheet with test data so folks can see it work.